# ffmpeg not converting entire video in java application

Tags: java, video, ffmpeg

My code converts a video into different formats (160p to 2160p). The codec of video with rotate tag 90 needs to be changed. below id the code for the same which works fine for all videos till date.

```
log_wfm.debug("Changing the codec video for file [" + orgFileName + "] and name of source file ["
                    + srcFileName + "]");
            String codecFlipCommand = "ffmpeg -i " + orgFileName + " -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast " + srcFileName;

            log_wfm.info("Executing command to change the codec of video!");
            fp = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(codecFlipCommand);

            inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fp.getInputStream()));
            outputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fp.getErrorStream()));

            StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
            String line;
            while ((line = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
                output.append(line).append('\n');
            }
            log_wfm.debug("stdInputForCodecChange: " + output);

            output = new StringBuffer();
            while ((line = outputStream.readLine()) != null) {
                output.append(line).append('\n');
            }
            log_wfm.debug("stdErrorForCodecChange: " + output);
```

now have a file of size 1.5Gb. The video does not create the file with changed codec. The file till size 848.5 MB is created and then the program hangs (with no exception or error logs)
Please suggest some way to finish this codec change process.
**The ffmpeg command converts the video, but via java application, the process hangs** 
Logs While converting via commandLine : 
    `ffmpeg version N-83433-ge87a4a8 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 6.3.1 (GCC) 20161221 (Red Hat 6.3.1-1)
  configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/root/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags='-L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib -ldl' --bindir=/root/bin --pkg-config-flags=--static --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265
  libavutil      55. 46.100 / 55. 46.100
  libavcodec     57. 75.100 / 57. 75.100
  libavformat    57. 66.101 / 57. 66.101
  libavdevice    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
  libavfilter     6. 73.100 /  6. 73.100
  libswscale      4.  3.101 /  4.  3.101
  libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libpostproc    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/home/urvashi/test/SachinSagaGameLaunchEvent.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2017-12-07T06:26:23.000000Z
    com.android.version: 7.1.1
Duration: 00:14:16.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 14231 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 13971 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 29.94 fps, 29.92 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : 2017-12-07T06:26:23.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-12-07T06:26:23.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
[libx264 @ 0x4601a20] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x4601a20] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x4601a20] profile Constrained Baseline, level 4.0
[libx264 @ 0x4601a20] 264 - core 148 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0
Output #0, mp4, to '/home/urvashi/test/Manual_SachinSagaGameLaunchEvent.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    com.android.version: 7.1.1
    encoder         : Lavf57.66.101
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1080x1920 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], q=-1--1, 29.92 fps, 11488 tbn, 29.92 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
      creation_time   : 2017-12-07T06:26:23.000000Z
      encoder         : Lavc57.75.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-12-07T06:26:23.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
      encoder         : Lavc57.75.100 aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help Past duration 0.600212 too large   48193kB time=00:00:27.26 bitrate=14479.2kbits/s speed=2.07x 
Past duration 0.998863 too large
frame=25611 fps= 55 q=-1.0 Lsize= 1721466kB time=00:14:16.04 bitrate=16473.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=17 speed=1.85x
video:1707295kB audio:13453kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.041757%
[libx264 @ 0x4601a20] frame I:103   Avg QP:22.16  size:242916
[libx264 @ 0x4601a20] frame P:25508 Avg QP:25.17  size: 67557`

Thanks in Advance.